# Dont use the bold version of a font if the regular doesnt exist

Tags: html, css

So I Use Droid Sans globally on my site. In some places I use the bold version, in others the regular.

Somehow one of our users encountered a bug, he doesnt have the regular version of Droid Sans installed on his computer, but he has the bold one, so my site defaults to the bold one.

Is there anyway to make my site not load droid sans at all if he doesnt have the normal one installed ?

Its just this one div that messes up my entire site if the text in it is bold. Im looking for a solution similiar to this.

```
.MyDivThatMessesUpStuff {

  Font-Family: "Droid sans(but only regular)", "others....";
}
```

So if the user doesnt have the regular version of droid sans, it defaults to the next font in line, and not to the bold one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of expecting user to have such font, better have it on server and apply proper CSS.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700);
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use google fonts, and import the corresponding font.
Check this [Droid Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans)